# Request.ServerVariables not updated when simultaneous login from 2 machines

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using IIS 7.0 on WS2008.

I've implemented a simple login page that redirects to another simple page showing the Request.ServerVariables key/values.
I'm using the built-in SQL membership provider.

The website is on a DEV machine and there are no users on it.

When I login at the same time with 2 different users from 2 different locations (2 different public addresses) then one of the Request.ServerVariables page is the same as the other.
That includes the client IP address which is then completely wrong.
The authentication as well as the other cookies are wrong as well.

I checked the IIS log and it shows the correct client address as well as the correct login name.

If I then reload the wrong page I get the correct data.

Is there some concurrency issue in ASP.NET? I disabled the session and caching but I still get the same behaviour.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same issue when we accidentally cached too heavily on the IIS. The website  simply returned whatever it had returned before.

Take a look at the site settings and see if you have any settings in the "Output Caching" of your website.

Comment: I checked again and OutputCaching is disabled at the IIS and application level (through the server admin interface).

Comment: It still smells very much like a caching issue somewhere on the way. Did you try 1. to disable client caching explicitly (Response.Cache.SetCacheability) or, somewhat counterintuitively, ENABLE IIS Output Caching, User-mode as well as Kernel-mode, and select "Prevent all caching" (though "Using file change notifications" should suffice in most conceivable setups), while making sure your file extensions match.

Comment: Or, of course, copy this question to the "Server Fault" platform.